Two power supplies at the same time
I'm planning to design a shield for the ESP32 DevKit. This shield will be powered from a 12v battery through a buck converter (to 3v3). My plan here is that I want to implement a circuit that lets the shield be powered only from the 12v power supply if the shield is connected through USB and to 12v simultaneously.
My question: what is the circuit i should use to only let one power source supplies the shield ? –
I'm a bit confused and thanks for you help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can isolate the sources with two schottky diodes in series with every source, but the battery voltage has to be a bit less than usb voltage.
I would use 2x li-ion or 6V lead-acid.


You want a redundant 3.3V supply but only exclusive to the higher source, namely USB = 5V+/-10%(?) and 12V+/-10%(?).
So 1st you must define "Design Specs" for min/max current temperature, voltage error and all other environmental and functional assumptions. As a professional R&D designer, this is how I was taught in Aerospace in the '70's and used in every major industry after that (Telecom R&D, HDD Mfg, AMR R&D).  Then you can Verify your Design with Tests (DVT) and choose stress tests to verify your design works and meets your specs.
Allow me to share some insights.
You can design for just functional specs, and at lowest cost and/or least voltage error. Pick one theme or rank in priority of choices then add to your "Design Spec".
Functions

Enable/disable current

Linear regulators only supply current to a load if its voltage is slightly higher than another source in parallel. Although they often limit the reverse voltage to -0.3V ( e.g. if input = 0V ) a Schottky diode from out to input is used to protect it from output still charged.  The reverse rating depends on the technology, FET or BJT.
Some Linear regulators have an enable input. Then all you need is a DC OK from the buck regulator or a slightly higher voltage by say >=0.1V to let the Linear reg. idle.
You don't want any interruption of 3.3V, when the 12V is plugged in. So this would exclude relays and switches with dead time.
Ideal FET Diode OR logic.**
With more cost and complexity "high man wins" logic enables a dual logic level FET MUX like the DW101A a holding cap reduces the glitch during deadtime switching to acceptable CPU noise levels.

Preferred choice

On the STM32 Dev. Board schematic they use two 1N5819 Sch. 1A diodes to the shared  "5V bus" now being ~ 4.6V used for USB logic.  This drives the SGM2212 600 mA CMOS LDO to 3.3V.
So whatever you choose for a stepdown converter adjust it to 5.1 to 5.2V so that it is asserted to supply the current.




modified source: https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/esp-idf/SCH_ESP32-S2-DEVKITC-1_V1_20220817.pdf
I suspect you might be interested in making a CNC Shield using at least a high power 12V supply for Stepper motors, laser etc.
A word of caution.
Although USB devices communicate very well when using host 5V  when each uses their own 5V beware that floating SMPS have a great deal of CM noise which becomes differential on DC pairs with unbalanced AC impedance > 1MHz and this will cause data errors. (experience told me a Laptop with a charger sometimes fails with some towers but if both ends are floating it may be OK. The isolation transformer pF leakage and/or X cap line filter in the SMPS are the usual culprits for CM leakage noise on USB. Use a PE ground to the Shield's 0V or try a series metal film cap. connection using braided wire from the host Gnd to suppress the Vcm noise on a floating Shield's 12V supply. An alternative is to add a large mu CM choke/Balun on the 12Vin of the 12V supply switching rate is fast enough. You can also unplug a laptop charger if it is the host.
